# How to deploy folders inside WEB-INF

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea

I have a Spring project in IntelliJ Idea. I have a folder inside WEB-INF called data.

I would like to know how to deploy `WEB-INF/data/*` files, because it seems as if by default, `data` folder does not gets copied to final package.

Comment: What build tool are you using?

Comment: It is a Spring Web Application, IntelliJ Idea, Maven